# How to sum columns in a data table data row horizontally and add result in new column?

Tags: datatable

How can I get a sum for all the columns in a data table?

Say I had the following table. How can I calculate the "Sum" of row? It should be easy to add total row to a data table.

The Columns No 4 is the Sum of Col1+Col2+Col3.... How Can I Do this for N Number of Columns... Without Loop

```
Rows                  Col1        Col2      Col3    Col4
1                      12         1         23       36
2                       1         0          5       6
3                       6         2          9       16
```

Comment: You need to tell us a bit more. Is this SQL? .NET? JS?, Python? etc etc.

Comment: Hover your mouse over the `datatable` tag you added to your question, and read the notes: "_The term "datatable" is ambiguous..._" The text also gives you suggestions for what tags you can use instead.

Comment: Also, why must this be done "_Without Loop_"?